# Conversion ByteBuffer to Image give noisy output

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-bitmap, bytebuffer

I am trying to convert ByteBuffer to Bitmap Image but the output I get is noisy i.e not what I had expected. My code is as follows:

```
private Bitmap getOutputImage(ByteBuffer output){
        output.rewind();

        int outputWidth = 384;
        int outputHeight = 384;
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(outputWidth, outputHeight, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        int [] pixels = new int[outputWidth * outputHeight];
        for (int i = 0; i < outputWidth * outputHeight; i++) {
            //val a = 0xFF;
            //float a = (float) 0xFF;

            //val r: Float = output?.float!! * 255.0f;
            //byte val = output.get();
            float r = ((float) output.get()) * 255.0f;

            //val g: Float = output?.float!! * 255.0f;
            float g = ((float) output.get()) * 255.0f;

            //val b: Float = output?.float!! * 255.0f;
            float b = ((float) output.get()) * 255.0f;


            //pixels[i] = a shl 24 or (r.toInt() shl 16) or (g.toInt() shl 8) or b.toInt()
            pixels[i] = (((int) r) << 16) | (((int) g) << 8) | ((int) b);
        }
        bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, outputWidth, 0, 0, outputWidth, outputHeight);

        return bitmap;
    }
```

The out image I am getting is

[image]

Please advise me what is wrong here?

Comment: We can't tell whether the problem is the data that you've got in your `ByteBuffer` (which we don't know anything about) or the `setPixels` call. I suggest you separate those two entirely. For example, try writing code with no input, but which creates an image with three wide solid bars: one red, one green, one blue. When you've got that working, you'll know what to put into `pixels`... you can then look at what's in your `ByteBuffer` as an entirely separate thing.

Comment: I have a tensorflow lite model that gives an image as output in the form of ByteBuffer and I am looking to convert this ByteBuffer by the function given above but the output I get is corrupted. So, please look at the function and tell me about the issue.

Comment: I've already suggested how to proceed. We have no idea what format the data in the ByteBuffer is - you're assuming it's 3-pixels-per-byte (RGB) but you haven't given us any evidence to support that assumption. Have you tried any of what I suggested in the previous comment?

Answer (score 0):

output.get() is read 1byte from buffer.
maybe you have to change output.get() to output.getFloat()

then well work.

this is my code.

```
 ByteBuffer modelOutput = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(200 * 200 * 3 * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

 Interpreter tflite = getTfliteInterpreter("ESRGAN.tflite");
 tflite.run(input, modelOutput);

 modelOutput.rewind();

 int outputWidth = 200;
 int outputHeight = 200;

 Bitmap bitmap2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(outputWidth, outputHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

 int [] pixels = new int[outputWidth * outputHeight];
 for (int i = 0; i < outputWidth * outputHeight; i++) {
      int a = 0xFF;

      float r = (modelOutput.getFloat());
      float g = (modelOutput.getFloat());
      float b = (modelOutput.getFloat());

      pixels[i] = a << 24 | ((int) r << 16) | ((int) g << 8) | (int) b;
 }

 bitmap2.setPixels(pixels, 0, outputWidth, 0, 0, outputWidth, outputHeight);
```